# Incorrect unit scraping by prometheus jmx agent

Tags: prometheus, grafana, jmx-exporter

I have setup jmx agent, prometheus and grafana. The metrics are being scraped correctly from kafka application. But metrics like latency need to be in seconds, miliseconds or nanoseconds but they are being scraped as a floating point number. When I display this metric on grafana it is not able to convert this floating number to time. How to solve this

I have tried checking the configs and surfing the net but couldn’t find anything.

Comment: Are you looking for how to specify units on your graph? If so: Panel options > Standard options > Unit